# Good practices in typescript/vue for testing

Tags: typescript, vue.js, testing, vitest

I'm relatively new to vue and typescript and wanted to ask what good practices are for this specific case: 
I have two different components that share the same logic to export text files (txt, pdf, etc.). I extracted these methods into a typescript file called exportUtility, which looks like the following:

```
export interface ExportOptions<T> {
  name: string;
  fileType: string;
  generateContent: (results: T[]) => string;
}

export function generateFileName(format: string, prefix: string) {
  //some code
  return fileName;
}

export function saveFile(content: string, fileName: string, fileType: string) {
  //some code
  link.click(); //downloads the file locally
}

export function exportResults<T>(
  results: T[],
  selectedOptions: ExportOptions<T>[],
  prefix: string
) {
  selectedOptions.forEach((option) => {
    const content = option.generateContent(results as T[]);
    const fileName = generateFileName(option.name, prefix);
    saveFile(content, fileName, option.fileType);
  });
}
```

I tried to write unit tests for each method. The first two methods were fairly easy, but the test for the  `exportResults` method did not work like I imagined it. We are using vitest and I tried to spy on (`vi.spyOn`) the `generateFileName` and the `saveFile` method. But this does not work.
Now I wonder if I'm approaching it wrong, because is it good practice to mock other methods in a unit test from the same module?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "generateFileName and the saveFile method" - they are functions, not methods. You can't spy on something you use in the same module. Either test them as a single unit or split to multiple modules

Comment: Thanks for the clarification between methods and functions. I tested both of them independently, but how do I test the exportResults function? I wanted to test if it calls the two other functions, but this seems to be the wrong way.

Comment: As said, they should be in different modules if you want to test them separately, otherwise you need to test exportResults only because this covers all functions

Comment: Ok, I get it. But putting them in different moduls, for like 5 lines would be a little bit over the top or wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's the decision that's based on practical concerns. If these 5 lines were proven to be error-prone and need separate tests then this would make sense, otherwise it's the same as if exportResults contained code from generateFileName, etc